# Font not displaying in Safari

Tags: html, css, fonts, safari

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Gotham';
  src: url('../../assets/fonts/GothamBook.ttf') format('truetype'),
    url('../../assets/fonts/gothambook-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
    url('../../assets/fonts/gothambook-webfont.woff2') format('woff2');
  font-weight: 400;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Gotham';
  src: url('../../assets/fonts/GothamBold.ttf') format('truetype'),
      url('../../assets/fonts/gothambold-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
      url('../../assets/fonts/gothambold-webfont.woff2') format('woff2');
  font-weight: 700;
}

body {
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  font-family: 'Gotham', 'Arial', 'Helvetica', sans-serif;
}
```

See above css. This works fine on Chrome, Firefox and Edge. But in Safari the text sometimes simply doesn't show. So it doesn't even go to the fallback, it just doesn't show.

This seems to be especially the case when the text is dynamically inserted with JavaScript. I can see the text in the inspector but not in the viewport. It always shows up when using:

```
font-family: 'Helvetica', sans-serif;
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your Safari version does not support the fonts, maybe you can change into another one.

E.g.:

```css
font-family: "Georgia", "Times New Roman", //[...]
```

Comment: Isn't the fallback font meant for unsupported fonts?

Comment: I understand your confusion, but perhaps, (I'm not a pro,）that the core of Safari cannot compile these fonts.